# Pandas - convert every row to a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame.

```
                                profile_id         companyName                                  title
0  ACoAABTDOXgBMlsNG44iUdoDo0lCc1HcheRnMfg  Project A Ventures                                    CMO
1  ACoAABTDOXgBMlsNG44iUdoDo0lCc1HcheRnMfg  Project A Ventures           Head of Customer Acquisition
2  ACoAABTDOXgBMlsNG44iUdoDo0lCc1HcheRnMfg            Facebook  Client Solutions Manager (Disruptors)
3  ACoAABTDOXgBMlsNG44iUdoDo0lCc1HcheRnMfg  Project A Ventures       Senior Display Marketing Manager
4  ACoAABTDOXgBMlsNG44iUdoDo0lCc1HcheRnMfg  Project A Ventures              Display Marketing Manager
```

My goal is to convert every row to a single column like this. Basically, I have 5 companies and 5 titles for one profile id and I want to have a single row per profile id.
[image]

**Edit: The number of companies/titles can differ per profile.**

I've tried pivoting but it doesn't seem to work for this case.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be as follows:

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'profile_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
        'companyName': [*'ABCAB'],
        'title': [*'XYZYZ']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

   profile_id companyName title
0           1           A     X
1           1           B     Y
2           1           C     Z
3           2           A     Y
4           2           B     Z
```

**Pivot**

- Use [`df.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc=list` to get each `profile_id` in a single row with the values for `companyName` and `title` as lists.
- Use the constructor [`df.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) on both columns (with `.tolist()`). This will expand the single columns into multiple columns with the individual items from the lists. Wrap this inside [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to get one `df` again.
- At this stage, we'll have `res.columns` as `Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')`. I.e. `0,1,2` cols for `companyName`, and same for `title`. We are looking for `0,0,1,1,2,2`, so let's apply `res = res.loc[:, res.columns.unique()]`.
- Finally, use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to rename all the columns.

```
tmp = df.pivot_table(index='profile_id',values=['companyName','title'],aggfunc=list)
res = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(tmp[col].tolist(), 
                              index=tmp.index)
                 for col in tmp.columns], axis=1)

res = res.loc[:, res.columns.unique()]

from itertools import cycle
res.columns = [f'{j}{int(i)+1}' for i, j in zip(res.columns, cycle(tmp.columns))]

print(res)

           companyName1 title1 companyName2 title2 companyName3 title3
profile_id                                                            
1                     A      X            B      Y            C      Z
2                     A      Y            B      Z         None   None
```